# Ansible escaping dots to use with map function as attributes

Tags: ansible, escaping, yaml, jinja2

I have key of an object variable I can't escape in Ansible playbook, possibly because of containing dots,

Here's the data structure of `variable`:

```
"results":[
  {
    //snip//

    "changed": false,
    "hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout": "abc",

    //snip//
  },
  {
    //snip//

    "changed": true,
    "hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout": "xyz",

    //snip//
  }
]
```

I'm unable to extract `"hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout"` inside it with this playbook,

```
  - debug:
       msg: "{{variable.results | map(attribute='hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout') }}"
```

While I can get other value just fine,

```
      - debug:
          msg: "{{variable.results | map(attribute='changed') }}"
```

I tried with `\` , `'.'`, and `{{...}}` to escape `.` (dot) but still no luck. 
I suspect it's `.` because of this error message:

```
  msg: |-
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'hostvars[item]'
```

When running `ansible-playbook -vvv` command

How I can map `"hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout"` ?

Comment: Please post a full self-contained example. I have trouble to follow you issue in a snippet form.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin, Sorry, I hope it's clearer now...

Comment: Uh... I'd say you have an extremely unusual key. Can you make it a bit less strange in the place you save them?

It's indeed, some kind of weird bug, but I never saw such keys in my practice.

Comment: I have to use that key to reference Ansible's hostvars to combine multiple host's result in commandResult. Yes I read elsewhere also still unresolved. :/

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I work it around by wrapping inside Ansible `set_fact` first:

```
  - set_fact:
    variable: "{{hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout_lines}}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['servers'] }}"
    register: all_result

  - debug:
        msg: "{{all_result.results |  map(attribute='ansible_facts') | list  | to_nice_json }}
```

The original question to escape dots remain unanswered, though.

Answer (score 0):

To address a key with dots, use array notation with single quotes instead of dot notation, i.e.:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{variable.results | map(attribute=['hostvars[item].commandResult.stdout']) }}"
```

This returns the value.

cf.: Ansible FAQ